# Move a jira issue between workflows

Tags: workflow, jira, jira-agile

I have an issue in JIRA that is following one workflow, workflow looks something like this (for bugs):

New -> Eval -> Approve -> Roadmap/Schedule -> Dev -> Complete

This workflow is for issue type "Bug".

For higher priority bugs, I want a totally different workflow, and for it to have its own issue type, for instance "Priority Bug".

R&D -> Dev -> Release -> Complete

This works great, for new Priority Bugs, but I have a transition, that allows you to promote a normal bug to a priority bug. That transition changes the issue type to Priority Bug properly, but when it gets there, it seems lost, its now not in either workflow. How do I get it to change workflows as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to install Script Runner plugin, and implement this as a single workflow. You can have custom scripted conditions that will check the type of the issue and allow and disallow your transitions thus emulating like it is a different workflow for another issue type.

Answer (score 0):

Workflows are for a given project and for a given issue type. If the bug is in a particular project and of a particular issue type then it will follow the corresponding workflow.

However, when moving from one workflow to another there needs to be some way for JIRA to know what state to go to. When you do a manual move you get a prompt that allows you to decide what state in the new workflow it has. I have never done an automatic move triggered by a transition, but I suspect it will have a problem determining what state the issue should have. Perhaps you could set the state as a part of the transition?